# Does using postincrement within a fold-expression give unsequenced behaviour?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, fold-expression

Recently I've came up with an idea how enumerate elements in a parameter pack (Pulses) and I've been happy with the solution for a while:

```
lastValue = 0.0; i = -1;
lastValue += (... + ((time <= endtimes[++i] && time >= delays[i]) ? static_cast<Pulses*>(fields[i])->operator()(time - delays[i]) : 0.0));
```

however now as I've tried to compile with Clang instead of GCC, I got the following warning

> warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]

I've read a couple of posts about unsequenced modifications, but in their examples the modification either happens two times in an expression or on left side of the "=" operator.

On the other hand my understanding is that parameter packs are evaluated sequentially, so... no unsequenced behaviour right? Or am I dead wrong here and the compiler is always right?

Comment: It could be a false positive because you both modify and use `i`. It *should* be sequenced properly but it's also hard to say since we don't have a [mcve]. What is the `...` supposed to be?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Looks like a fold expression to me.

Comment: The missing … aside, _if_ there is a problem either with the compiler or with some complicated language rule, this may be a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: @gnasher729: How is it reproducible? It will not compile to produce the error message asked about—the identifiers are all undeclared.

Comment: Fold-expression or not, is there sequencing for arithmetic operators? IIRC there's not, so if this *is* a fold-expression the modifications to `i` in `++i` will be unsequenced. And if it's not a fold-expression then it depends on if `i` is used or possibly modified in the missing `...` bit. So either way, we really need a proper [mcve] to give any definitive answers.

Comment: And either way, complex expressions like the one shown are really not something I would wish upon my worst enemy. Will you be able to understand and maintain this code in the future? Will others? The answer to both questions is "no". Simplify, break it out into multiple sub-expressions, and add comments and plenty of documentation about what's going on and why you do it the way you're doing it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well, the case is necessary, the operator() call as well, the only part that looks ugly to me is the i=-1. I would also happily, make a manual if statement if I could still use a parameter pack the way I do. This code uses class template argument and because of that will evaluate at compile-time, which is what I need.  At the end it's not the most complicated thing in the universe given the variable names.

Comment: *cast not case, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang is right, the code causes UB.

Evaluation rules for fold expressions are exactly the same as for normal expressions.

Evaluations of the two operands of `+` (and of most binary operators) is [unsequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) relative to one another (i.e. can happen in any order, possibly interleaved), and unsequenced changes of scalar variables cause UB.

The solution is simple: use operator `,` for folding, instead of `+`. For `,`, the first operand is fully evaluated before the second one, so there's a clear evaluation order and no UB.

```
lastValue = 0.0; i = -1;
((lastValue += ((time <= endtimes[++i] && time >= delays[i]) ? static_cast<Pulses*>(fields[i])->operator()(time - delays[i]) : 0.0)), ...);
```

Or, use a lambda to make it less ugly:

```
lastValue = 0.0; i = 0;
([&]{
    if (time <= endtimes[i] && time >= delays[i])
        lastValue += static_cast<Pulses*>(fields[i])->operator()(time - delays[i]);
    i++;
}(), ...);
```

Comment: According to the ccpreference the unary left fold actually should evaluate with braces: "Unary left fold (... op E) becomes (((E1 op E2) op ...) op EN)"

Comment: @Ranza Your quote doesn't actually say anything about the evaluation order. Let's say you have `(a() + b()) + c()` - then the three functions `a`, `b`, `c` can be called in any order. Same with your fold expression.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the compiler is always right, even when it’s wrong…

Unless i is used in the … that you removed, I can’t see what’s wrong. On the other hand, the expression is overly complex and could do with being split up, even just to make debugging easier.

Comment: *"`...` that you removed"* I bet that's a fold expression.